# i am not able to delete android studio completely from my device

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am a flutter developer and I wanted to clear reinstall the android with the latest version so I deleted android studio from the control panel from my windows os and then when I reinstalled my android studio everything got back as is when I deleted and I don't know why but then I deleted all related files from my storage I deleted filed form program files, the user (.android and .gradle ) then also from app data also from local and roaming and then I tried to reinstall it but the thing was as it is and I have done this several times but I can't seem to understand why it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all Uninstall android studio from the Settings.
2. Go to the location where your SDK is installed. In my case, I found it here `C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Android`. Delete the android folder.
3. Now in your user files, delete the .android, .gradle, such folders.
4. Now go to AppData and delete the folder named Google.
5. Restart your PC once.

Note: You can also delete the project files if you want.
If this doesn't help try reinstalling Flutter.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked it seems that some android files were left in the google directory which my file manager search wouldn't able to locate anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Search android studio in the Start window and delete all files.

Answer (score 0):

On the user directory C:\Users\USERNAME, you also need to delete all directories starting by '.AndroidStudio'.

Android Studio create those directories after each update, as backup. And will restore the backup after reinstall if present.

Comment: yes! I assure you there is no directory named android or Gradle in my whole pc I have spent more than 3 hrs deleting all those files but it seems that my user settings have been saved on my pc on the particular directory which does not have the name android or Gradle and every time I try to download the android studio it seems to automatically setup those settings with plugins